# Glimpse in a multi-layer application

Tags: glimpse

I have a multi-layer SOA system running on different servers. System has one web interface. All layers are connected via WCF. Is it possible to monitor, using Glimpse*, a request that goes from web down to the bottom most layer and response comes back to the web.

One of the layers is using Entity Framework.

I have Googled it but so far haven't found anything (so far). To be honest I didn't get a chance to spend enough time interrogating this because of time constraint.

Cheers in advance.

- Without extra coding or too much extra coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glimpse does not currently support this.

Comment: Interesting! Glimpse is pretty famous. I am surprised that Glimpse cant be used for an SOA styled system. Is there any other plug-in similar to Glimpse that will do the job? Anything from your personal experience?

Comment: I don't know of any free/open source tools that do this in the Windows space. There are plenty of paid for solutions (New Relic for example).